# Converting array of objects value into integer value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to javascript/typescript. currently have an array of objects

I would like to convert the value to a integer. Currently I am mapping the value by

```js
var k = [{key: "apples", value:"5"}, {key: "orange", value:"2"}];
var output = Object.entries(k).map(([key,value]) => ({key,value}));

console.log(output)
```

Expected output is

```
[{key: "apples", value:5}, {key: "orange", value:2}]
```

Comment: Can you please show us an example of what your desired output would be for your input provided above?

Comment: my desired output would be [{key: "apples", value:5}, {key: "orange", value:2}]. i tried parsing it as a integer but it complained that it could not be converted and i am confused about it

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `Object.entries()` on your array, you can simply apply `.map()` directly to your `k` array. For each object, you can destructure it to pull out its `value` property, which you can then map to a new object with the `value` converted to a number using the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) (`+value`) like so:

```js
const k = [{key: "apples", value:"5"}, {key: "orange", value:"2"}];
const output = k.map(({value, ...rest}) => ({...rest, value: +value}));

console.log(output)
```

If you wish to change your array in-place, you can loop over it's object using a `.forEach` loop, and change the `value` using dot-notation like so:

```js
const k = [{key: "apples", value:"5"}, {key: "orange", value:"2"}];

k.forEach(obj => {
  obj.value = +obj.value; // use `+` to convert your string to a number
});
console.log(k)
```