# How to convert Array of object value into a number

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

For example I have this Array:

```
 const arr = [
    {val1: '123', text: 'not a num', new:'123.34'},
    {val1: '123', text: 'not a number', new:'123.34'},
    {val1: '123', text: 'yahoo', new:'123.34'}
    ]
```

And I want to convert the keys `val1` and new into a `number`,

so I created this function:

```
const convertToNumbers = (arr: Array<{ unknown }>, keys: Array<string>) => {
  return arr.map((val) => {
    keys.map((k) => {
      console.log(val[k]);
      return (val[k] = +val[k]);
    });
   
  });
};
```

Expected result should be like this:

```
   const result = [
        {val1: 123, text: 'not a num', new:123.34},
        {val1: 123, text: 'not a number', new:123.34},
        {val1: 123, text: 'yahoo', new:123.34}
        ]
```

The function will accept both an Array(first param is the Array itself and the second contains the key to be converted into number).

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you want to do this in-place, or return a new array with copies of the objects with the appropriate keys converted?

Comment: You can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` to do the conversion

Comment: new Array is better

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` (`keys.map((k) => ...)`) then `.map()` is the wrong tool

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting array of objects value into integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656839/converting-array-of-objects-value-into-integer-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map new objects and convert wanted keys.

```js
const 
    array = [{ val1: '1,234', text: 'not a num', new:'123.34' }, { val1: '123', text: 'not a number', new:'123.34' }, { val1: '123', text: 'yahoo', new:'123.34' }],
    keys = ['val1', 'new'],
    result = array.map(object => ({
        ...object,
        ...Object.fromEntries(keys.map(key => [key, +object[key].replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')]))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm trying to delete the comma as well with this method [key, +object[key].replace(/,/g, '')] but with no luck

Comment: sorry I forgot to add in the example... For example 1,299 to 1299

Comment: you need a replacement of unwanted characters. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
    {val1: '123', text: 'not a num', new:'123.34'},
    {val1: '123', text: 'not a number', new:'123.34'},
    {val1: '123', text: 'yahoo', new:'123.34'}
    ]
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  text += arr[i].val1;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```